# How can I add a third conditional to ternary statement?

Tags: javascript

I have a search box with 3 radio buttons. The books and website radio buttons work. When you enter a term with either of those radio buttons selected, it performs the search accordingly. However, I want to add another condition so that when the second radio button (magazines) is ticked, it performs the search to that url. link to my fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/pk4mowfg/

This is the line I believe needs to be fixed in order to achieve the goal

```
searchType === 'website'? window.open(websiteUrl, '_blank')  : window.open(catalogUrl, '_blank');
```

```
<script>
let searchType = "catalog";
$("#catalog").prop('checked', true);

$("#editsubmit").click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  if ($("#q").val().length > 0){
  let term = $("#q").val().split(' ').join("%20");
  let websiteUrl = 'https://www.delawarelibrary.org/search/node/'+ term;
  let magUrl = 'https://ohioweblibrary.org/search/?q='+ term;
  let catalogUrl = 'https://catalog.clcohio.org/polaris/search/searchresults.aspx?ctx=106.1033.0.0.24&type=Keyword&term='+term;
    searchType === 'website'? window.open(websiteUrl, '_blank') : window.open(catalogUrl, '_blank');
  }
});

$('#frmSearch').keypress(function (e) {
  if ($("#q").val().length > 0){
  if(e.which == 13) {
    e.preventDefault();
    let term = $("#q").val().split(' ').join("%20");
    let websiteUrl = 'https://www.delawarelibrary.org/search/node/'+ term;
    let magUrl = 'https://ohioweblibrary.org/search/?q='+ term;
    let catalogUrl = 'https://catalog.clcohio.org/polaris/search/searchresults.aspx?ctx=106.1033.0.0.24&type=Keyword&term='+term;
    searchType === 'website'? window.open(websiteUrl, '_blank')  : window.open(catalogUrl, '_blank');

    }
  }
});

$("#catalog").click(function(){
  searchType = 'catalog';
});

$("#owl").click(function(){
  searchType = 'mag';
console.log('magclicked');
});


$("#site").click(function(){
  searchType = 'website';
});
</script>
```

Comment: Ternary [adj]: composed of three parts. (Use a `case` statement or nested `if` statements.)

Comment: Ternary operator means it has **3** arguments: the condition and the two return values. What you describe sounds like an `if/else` or even a `switch`. Why do you want to use ternary operators?

Comment: @VLAZ because I already had it setup this way    searchType === 'website'? window.open(websiteUrl, '_blank') : window.open(catalogUrl, '_blank');

Comment: @Abigail that's already a bad setup. The basic rule with ternary operators is that when you want to use one, think again if you really need it. And the second one is - don't use it as a shorter `if`. You're saving on what - few symbols? And some whitespace, I guess. Hardly worth it if you don't need a ternary.

Comment: Is there any way I can add to it though is my question so that the 3rd radio button will work

Comment: You will have to change the ternary to actual `if` statements or a `switch` statement to make it work with more options.

Comment: okay thanks @Herohtar

Comment: @Abigail a ternary_statement is an expression and the definition of a ternary statement is `condition ? expression : expression`. Since ternary statements are expressions you can do `condition ? ternary_statement : expression` or `condition ? expression : ternary_statement` or `condition ? ternary_statement : ternary_statement`. A word of warning though, without proper indentation this becomes unreadable really quickly

Answer (score 1):

instead of `if else` statements or  nested ternaries you can define a `urlMapper` object and a function that will map your `searchType` to urls

```
const urlMapper = {
  website: 'website url',
  catalog: 'catalog url'
}

const getUrl = searchType => urlMapper[searchType] || 'default url';

console.log(
  getUrl('website'),
  getUrl('catalog'),
  getUrl('unknown')
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use another ternary operation for the `else` portion of the previous ternary to chain them.

```
searchType === 'website'? window.open(websiteUrl, '_blank') : 
    searchType === 'catalog' ? window.open(catalogUrl, '_blank') :
        window.open(magUrl, '_blank');
```

Comment: It's also possible to do it in the `if` portion but that is not commonly done

Comment: @slebetman this is true. Never thought about using it that way.